# Increment column value on certain condition in SQL query on Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I want aggregate my walks with animals by weeks groupping my rows in 1 group if break between weeks was greater than 2 weeks.

I have my table:

```
Create table test.walk (animal text, week integer)
```

with row for each walk i want to group:

```
insert into test.walk values ('DOG', 2)
insert into test.walk values ('DOG', 3)
insert into test.walk values ('DOG', 4)
insert into test.walk values ('CAT', 1)
insert into test.walk values ('CAT', 1)
insert into test.walk values ('CAT', 11)
insert into test.walk values ('CAT', 12)
insert into test.walk values ('CAT', 13)
```

I struggle with dense_rank() and lag() window functions, but have no luck to get additional column where I should get 3 distinct values as a result.

Here is my desired output:

[image]

What combination of window functions should I use to get two WALK_NO for CAT?
(becase after week 1 cat waited for me longer that 2 weeks)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `lag()` and cumulative sum:

```
with query as (
select w.*,
       sum(case when week < prev_week + 2 then 0 else 1 end) over (partition by animal order by week) as grp
from (select w.*,
             lag(week) over (partition by animal order by week) as prev_week
      from test.walk w
     ) w
)
select
    animal, week, grp,
    dense_rank() over (order by animal, grp) as grp2
from query
```

[image: Query output]

Note:  This will restart the counting over for each animal -- which seems to be the actual intention of what you want to do.  The definition of the problem is a bit tricky if you want the groups separated by animal, but to be incremental.  One method is:

```
select w.*,
       sum(case when prev_week = week then 0 else 1 end) over (order by min_week, animal, week) as grp
from (select w.*,
             lag(week) over (partition by animal order by week) as prev_week,
             min(week) over (partition by animal) as min_week
      from test.walk w
     ) w;
```

Comment: Thanks @Gordon Linoff but 1st query returns 4 values in grp column, -there should be 3. And DOG rows should be in one group.
2nd query has similiar problem...

Comment: @TommyLeeJoneswSciganym . . . I neglected the "2 week part".  Good morning.

Comment: in second query in grp column we have 7 groups, but It should be 3.

Comment: @TommyLeeJoneswSciganym . . . With the change I just made?

Comment: I had to use additional dense_rank() with the first query you provided but you helped a lot! Thanks @Gordon

Comment: @TommyLeeJoneswSciganym . . . The second does seem to do exactly what you want . . . but the `dense_rank()` is also a very reasonable solution.

Comment: In second I get 7 groups.. maybe different Postgresql version..? I use 9.5

Comment: In second I had to correct condition to: when week < prev_week + 2